# Writing a duplet in Lilypond

Tags: notation, lilypond, tuplet

How can one write a duplet consisting of two quarter notes equal to a dotted-quarter note in 6/8 time? Like this:

[image: duplet]

I tried `\tuplet 2/1.` but the `.` is not accepted.

And if I write this:

```
\tuplet 2/3 {<mi la>4 <mi la>} <re sol>4 <sol si>8 <sol si>8
```

I get this:

[image: wrong duplet]

Comment: Your first example was quite different.  This one has no time signature, so we'd have to guess that it's   6/8.  So long as you *are* working in some multiple of 3/8, a   Duplet makes sense.   If you are in  X/4,  use Richard's setup.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, wanted to write 6/8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix here would be `\tuplet 2/3 { c8 c }`, which tells LilyPond "write two eighth notes in the span of three." This gives:

[image]

But I would personally find this confusing for a few reasons, so I might suggest instead something like `c8 c c c8~ c16 c~ c8`, which gives:

[image]

---

**Edit:** Now that I see the example, I wonder if there's an error in the original that you're copying. A duplet *should* be two units played in the duration normally occupied by three units, so the score example you're working with, in my opinion, *should* be written as `\tuplet 2/3 { <e a>8 q } <d g>4 <g b>8`:

[image]

But if we really want quarter notes there, thankfully LilyPond allows us to alter the actual durations; just "multiply" the note values by the given amount. So now we can use `\tuplet 2/3 { <e a>4*1/2 q } <d g>4 <g b>8` to *notate* quarter notes, but the `*1/2` means that they only occupy half that value (that is, eighth notes) in the score:

[image]

Comment: Since my first reaction to the top form is (since this is the first measure) that it's starting on the off-beat of One and is purely eighth-notes, I definitely prefer the second.

Comment: I updated my question because on the partition I got you can see there are two quarter notes in the duplet.

Comment: So, what I want is: write two quarter notes in the span of one and a half".

Comment: @Lhooq Hopefully the edit is more helpful!

Comment: I must admit I was kind of confused with these two quarters note but, sir, you rock with your complete answer!

Comment: Anytime, happy to help!

Comment: You could also use dotted eighth notes.  This seems to me much less confusing than the eighth-to-sixteenth ties, especially where the tie conflicts with the barring.